# I get overflow encountered in double_scalars & invalid value encountered in double_scalars error in backward euler

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to plot the backward Euler method for different dts, the code looks like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def newton(x_old, t_new, dt, precision=1e-12):
    """ Takes values x_old and t_new, and finds the root of the
    function f(x_new), returning x_new. """

    # initial guess:
    x_new = x_old
    f = func(x_new, x_old, t_new, dt)
    dfdx = dfuncdx(t_new, dt)

    while abs(f / dfdx) > precision:
        x_new = x_new - f / dfdx
        f = func(x_new, x_old, t_new, dt)
        dfdx = dfuncdx(t_new, dt)

    return x_new


def func(x_new, x_old, t_new, dt):
    """ The function f(x) we want the root of."""
    return x_new - x_old - dt * (-2*x_new*t_new)


def dfuncdx(t_new, dt):
    """ The derivative of f(x) with respect to x_new."""
    return 1 + dt * (-2*t_new)


dts = np.array([0.2, 0.15, 0.1, 0.01])

plt.figure()
for i, dt in enumerate(dts):
    t_max = 10  
    N = int(t_max / dt)

    t = np.linspace(0, 10, N + 1)
    x = np.zeros(N + 1)

    t[0] = 0
    x[0] = 1


    for n in range(N):
        x[n + 1] = newton(x[n], t[n + 1], dt)


    plt.plot(t, x)

t = np.linspace(0, 10, 10000)
plt.plot(t, np.exp(-t**2))
plt.xlabel(r'$t$')
plt.ylabel(r'$x(t)$')
plt.legend([r'$\Delta t=$ %0.2f' % dts[0], r'$\Delta t=$ %0.2f' % dts[1], r'$\Delta t=$ %0.2f' % dts[2],
            r'$\Delta t=$ %0.2f' % dts[3], r'Exact solution'])
plt.grid();

plt.show()
```

The code finishes and I also get what it seems the right solutions, but the graphs are cut off before they should and I don't understand why. I also get overflow encountered in double_scalars & invalid value encountered in double_scalars error.

Comment: it seems the error lies somewhere at ```   x_new = x_new - f / dfdx ``` it blows out to e307 before it wirtes inf.

Comment: also it seems that f becomes nan after a couple of steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am stupid and made an error in the derivative :/
this works now

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def newton(x_old, t_new, dt, precision=1e-6):
    """ Takes values x_old and t_new, and finds the root of the
    function f(x_new), returning x_new. """

    # initial guess:
    x_new = x_old
    f = func(x_new, x_old, t_new, dt)
    dfdx = dfuncdx(t_new, dt)

    while abs(f / dfdx) > precision:
        x_new = x_new - f / dfdx
        f = func(x_new, x_old, t_new, dt)
        dfdx = dfuncdx(t_new, dt)

    return x_new


def func(x_new, x_old, t_new, dt):
    """ The function f(x) we want the root of."""
    return x_new - x_old - dt * (-2*x_new*t_new)


def dfuncdx(t_new, dt):
    """ The derivative of f(x) with respect to x_new."""
    return 1 + dt * (2*t_new)

dts = np.array([0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.0001])


plt.figure()
for i, dt in enumerate(dts):
    t_max = 10  # maximum time
    N = int(t_max / dt)

    t = np.linspace(0, 10, N + 1)
    x = np.zeros(N + 1)

    t[0] = 0
    x[0] = 1

    t_old = t[0]
    x_old = x[0]

    for n in range(N):
        x[n + 1] = newton(x[n], t[n + 1], dt)
        t[n + 1] = t[n] + dt

    # Plot the solution
    plt.plot(t, x)

t = np.linspace(0, 10, 10000)
plt.plot(t, np.exp(-t**2))
plt.xlabel(r'$t$')
plt.ylabel(r'$x(t)$')
plt.legend([r'$\Delta t=$ %0.2f' % dts[0], r'$\Delta t=$ %0.2f' % dts[1], r'$\Delta t=$ %0.2f' % dts[2],
            r'$\Delta t=$ %0.2f' % dts[3], r'Exact solution'])
plt.grid();

plt.show()
```